# Xamarin.Forms Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch

```
Native stack trace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104e4d1e6 __exceptionPreprocess + 294
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000112c18031 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104e52472 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 98
3   Foundation                          0x0000000105a7d652 -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 193
4   UIKit                               0x0000000109bd4b96 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 3064
5   UIKit                               0x0000000109f96e4a __111-[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:]_block_invoke + 866
6   UIKit                               0x000000010a369909 +[_UICanvas _enqueuePostSettingUpdateTransactionBlock:] + 153
7   UIKit                               0x0000000109f96a86 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability _scheduleFirstCommitForScene:transition:firstActivation:completion:] + 236
8   UIKit                               0x0000000109f972a7 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 675
9   UIKit                               0x000000010a9084d4 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 299
10  UIKit                               0x000000010a90836e -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 433
11  UIKit                               0x000000010a5ec62d __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 221
12  UIKit                               0x000000010a7e7387 _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100
13  UIKit                               0x000000010a5ec4f7 -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 223
14  UIKit                               0x000000010a368fb0 -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392
15  UIKit                               0x0000000109bd2f0c -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 515
16  UIKit                               0x000000010a1a5a97 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 361
17  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000117f362f3 -[FBSSceneImpl _didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 331
18  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000117f3ecfa __56-[FBSWorkspace client:handleCreateScene:withCompletion:]_block_invoke_2 + 225
19  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011356f779 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000113574931 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 317
21  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000117f6a470 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
22  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000117f6a12e -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 439
23  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000117f6a68e -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
24  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104defbb1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104dd44af __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 271
26  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104dd3a6f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263
27  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104dd330b CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 635
28  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001165faa73 GSEventRunModal + 62
29  UIKit                               0x0000000109bd60b7 UIApplicationMain + 159
30  ???                                 0x0000000133339607 0x0 + 5153986055
31  ???                                 0x0000000133339373 0x0 + 5153985395
```

Comment: Please show the associated code

Comment: Well, this is probably more of a Xamarin issue. The exception tells eyou xactly what wrong. How are you setting your root view controller in whatever funky thing Xamarin provides. If this were an actual iOS SDK question, we could probably tell you where your issue.

Comment: If you are having this error when using Xamarin Forms you should probably check if your initial page is properly constructed. This happens when XF fails to create your initial page and just continues running.

Comment: @BrunoCaceiro Thank you for your answer. Kindly post this as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are having this error when using Xamarin Forms you should probably check if your initial page is properly constructed. This happens when XF fails to create your initial page and just continues running.

Comment: Just a note to perhaps help others - if you run the Xamarin Forms project in Android emulator it will run the application but not present the application.

If you look in the output window now you will see the error (mine was a missing static resource).